# How to override third-party bundle form - Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, bundles

I am trying to override a form in Symfony. The third party bundle is [private-message-bundle : firediy](https://packagist.org/packages/firediy/private-message-bundle)

This is the 3rd party bundle form:

```
     $builder
        ->add('recipients', null, array(
            'label'              => 'form.recipients',
            'translation_domain' => 'FDPrivateMessageBundle',
        ))
        ->add('subject', null, array(
            'label'              => 'form.subject',
            'translation_domain' => 'FDPrivateMessageBundle',
        ))
        ->add('firstMessage', PrivateMessageType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
        ));
```

The `->add recipients`  part returns all the users and lists them for me to select several of them. I want to be able to give the bundle one recipient by default. I have tried to create a class `ConversationType` under `Form` and writing the following code:

```
    $builder->add('recipients', EntityType::class, array(
        'class'         => 'AppBundle:User',
        'multiple'      => true,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->where('u.id', $id);
        },
        .....
    ));
```

But I don't think the class is overriding the bundle because no changes made are effected.

What is the right way to do this? If my question is not clear enough, please let me know.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: The bundle provides a way to override the form, so it should be easy. Can you copy and paste the full ConversationType class?

Comment: I have tried that @Strnm . No changes made are effected. I've edited my question to clarify

Comment: based on what you posted I can't tell you much, please update your question with the full content of your ConversationType class and your services.yml (which is where you got the error you deleted on your edit)

Comment: The cause of the error was in the code `use FD\PrivateMessageBundle\Form\ConversationType as BaseType;` as provided by the bundle instead of `use FD\PrivateMessageBundle\Form\Type\ConversationType as BaseType;` . Note the `Type` which is missing from their example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar example of how form fields are overriden or extended: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

The example is based on overriding FosUser register form:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

As you can see you must specify the parent form you want to extend.